# Pentaho, trying to merge a small list of cities with a big list of person using same Key field

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

im trying to merge two lists, for both list i added a sequence to count to a maximium of 18, because i have a list of 18 cities.

This is my transformation:
[image]

Basically i added the city_ID-Sequence to do a sequence to a maximum of 18 since my text file ID, have a field "ID" with a maximum of 18.
The idea  would be when merging on "merge join 2", would merge with every thing with the same ID, repeating the cities name on the "csv file input 2", making easy for me to not generate by hand the cities names.

This is the result when i merge on "Merge Join 2":

[image]

I try to the the merge with a full outer join, and i made sure i had the right ID. What i pretend is when merging on "merge join 2" the cities names repeat down the line.

This is my citie List:

[image]

This is my people list after adding the city_ID sequence:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. The Add sequence step (that city_ID-sequence) would add values sequencially from 1 to 18 and then start again, so you are adding the cities to your csv "randomly", just from 1 to 18 in the order you are reading the csv, so each 18 rows of your input file will have the same city_ID, but there's not logic to the city assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The **Merge join** step needs the input rows ordered by the key you are using to join, so you need a Sort step before each branch of the Merge join.

I assume that in the "Merge join" you are joining by ID_Client, since you are adding that ID_Client to both files using a sequence, and the sequence provides the rows ordered, then in this case is not necessary, but in "Merge join 2" you are joining by ID in the rows coming from "Text file input" and by City_ID in the rows coming from "Merge join", so you need to add one Sort step after the "Text file input" step to sort by ID (yes, not needed in this particular case, but it's good practice in case your file isn't ordered) and another Sort step after the "Merge join" step to order the rows by City_ID.

Add those **Sort** steps always before a **Merge join** (unless you have added it before and you haven't changed the order in the following steps) even if you think you don't need them because the files come ordered or you are querying a table using a Sort by. Pentaho uses java internally, so with keys based on character columns or date columns the order based in your language might be not the same order java uses internally due to special characters.

Beware also that the Sort step by default treats cases as the same character ("A" the same as "a") unless you check specifically to treat them as different, the Merge join step treats them different and you'll find mismatches due to that annoying default in Pentaho.